# Google Column Chart Draws Y Axis Values Mixed

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization

Google Column Chart Drawing Y Axis values mix as you see in image below. I want to be Y values should be increased in ordinary.

[image]

**Jquery**

```
var result_glb;
$.post(base_url+"dashboard/get_bar_chart_data",function(result){
  result_glb = $.parseJSON(result);
}).done(function(){
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result_glb);

    var options = {
      vAxis : { format: 'decimal' },
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      colors: ['#08A3CC', '#89C4F4', '#02617A','#42617A']
      
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    //chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options)); has been tried.
  }
});
```

**Result of the request**
[image]

My results is not in ordinary increased but Column chart puts them like increasing day by day and after that place the Y values for each bar. Is there any option of the chart to handle this problem?

Comment: the main issue is the data exists in columns, its not possible to sort columns, only rows. would need to create custom data table with values in the order you need, which might also require custom column roles, if colors and tooltips are important -- which _material_ charts do not support...

Comment: Should I define different columns for each bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could manually re-order the values for each column

```
for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
  var colValues = [];
  for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
    colValues.push(data.getValue(r, c));
  }
  colValues.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
    data.setValue(r, c, colValues[c - 1])
  }
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result_glb);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['2017-06-01', 165, 938, 522, 998, 450, 250],
    ['2017-06-02', 135, 1120, 599, 1268, 288, 250],
    ['2017-06-03', 157, 1167, 587, 807, 397, 250],
    ['2017-06-04', 139, 1110, 615, 968, 215, 250],
    ['2017-06-05', 136, 691, 629, 1026, 366, 250]
  ]);

  for (var r = 0; r < data.getNumberOfRows(); r++) {
    var colValues = [];
    for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
      colValues.push(data.getValue(r, c));
    }
    colValues.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    for (var c = 1; c < data.getNumberOfColumns(); c++) {
      data.setValue(r, c, colValues[c - 1])
    }
  }

  var options = {
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['#08A3CC', '#89C4F4', '#02617A','#42617A']
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_material"></div>
```

however, re-ordering the column values will remove any relationship to the column heading.

which means values originally in column A, may now be in column F...

Comment: I'm getting this error. 
loader.js:215 Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 0.347 does not match type string in column index 1

Comment: I solved my problem by rounding the values in 2 precision. When my values comes like 0.25, 0.37, 0.50, there is no problem in the table but I tried your solutions in another page with the same values; it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the numbers were added as text in the json data, the y-axis will not be correctly ordered. Make sure you cast numbers to a numeric type when adding to your php array.
Php example:

```
   $out[$outlineindex][$outdbcolindex] = (float)$val['MyNumber'];
```

This will not solve your bar-sorting problem, but it will fix your y-axis, which is scrambled in your graph example.

Comment: please add detail showing why this is necessary, since the OP has already accepted an answer as having solved the problem